# Collapse allready expanded div

Tags: jquery, css

I trying to make a expand and collapse work on some divs. But i can't make it work. My problem is that it won't collapse on a click, if element already is expanded.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".employee").click( function() {  
    $(".employeeInfo").hide();   
if ($(this).children(".employeeInfo").css('display') == 'none') {        
    $(this).children(".employeeInfo").show();
} else {    
       $(this).children(".employeeInfo").hide(); 
}   });})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="employee">name
<div class="employeeInfo">info etc.</div></div>

<div class="employee">name
<div class="employeeInfo">info etc.</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { 
width: 400px; 
margin-bottom: 20px; 
margin-left: 5px; 
cursor: pointer; }

div.employee{ 
background: #ccc; }

div.employeeInfo { 
margin-left: 5px; 
display: none; }
```

I think the problem is on this line:

```
if ($(this).children(".employeeInfo").css('display') == 'none') {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".employee").click( function() {  
    $(this).children(".employeeInfo").toggle();   
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: I used $(".employee").click( function() {  
    $(this).children(".employeeInfo").toggle(); and it worked!! nice thanks for helping.. :) Sry cant vote your answer up, im a new user..